# TriggerUserEmail not sending an email as expected on Task Insert

Tags: apex, email, activity-settings

Deliverability for the org is `All Email`

`Enable User Control over Task Assignment Notifications` is enabled for the org

I've confirmed that users have `Email me when a task is assigned to me` selected for their user record...

Yet this snippet of code creates a task and DOES NOT send an email to the assigned user...  Is there any other setting I'm missing for this to work?

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlOptions = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
dmlOptions.EmailHeader.TriggerUserEmail= true;
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.Insert(taskRecord, dmlOptions);
```

Also, I confirmed that there are no errors (i.e. `sr.isSuccess()` is true)